# highmaps turboThreshold not working

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to resolve this [error12](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12) of highmaps as I have big array , but its not resolving here is a code snippet

```
 var options = {
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    turboThreshold:2000,
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return "myTool tip"
        }
    },}
```

any help will be appreciated...!!

Comment: You have objects in your data.

Comment: @Ondkloss it worked now I was putting it in the wrong way I had a series with zip code  and it worked when put in this way and yes it array of objects {
        name: 'cities',
        turboThreshold: 4000,
        type: 'mappoint',
        data: dataHolder,
    }